# Object Variable not set on Comments within Cells

Tags: excel, vba, comments

I'm trying to determine the length of a cell's comment but I get an object variable not set when there is no comment within the Cell.

`Len(Range("C8").Comment.Text)`

Comment: What is that you are trying to do>?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in that case `Range("C8").Comment` is `Nothing`, so the code fails when trying to retrieve the `Text` property of `Nothing`.

You need a null check:

```
If Not Range("C8").Comment Is Nothing Then
    length = Len(Range("C8").Comment.Text)
End If
```